# 400 Bad Request for Salesforce Platform APIs in Android Version 6

Tags: api, android, sfdcmobilesdk-android, api-version

We are facing an issue with our mobile application, we face issue(400 bad request) when calling Salesforce Platform API to get specific records of custom object(sObject Contact Association). And this is an issue only in Android version 6 and 5. This api works fine when using Android version >= 7. The other thing to note here is the issue started occurring since last couple of weeks.

We found this URL https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000352687&language=en_US&mode=1&type=1 that mentions that the support for Android 6 is retiring from Summer'20 release. Does it mean that Salesforce Platform API too will not work on Android Version <7?

Following is the API we are calling from mobile side, which throws error in Android 6 & 5, whereas it works fine in Android version >=7.
https://xxxxxxxxxxx_SObjectContactAssociation__c+WHERE+xxxxx__Contact__c =+'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

Below are the mobile device on which we are facing issues.
Device: Moto E3 & Samsung
Android Version: 6, 6.1 & 5

If anyone is facing such issue and could help us for the workaround for this will be appreciated.

Also if anyone could help with us with below questions:

1. Where we need to look for changes to mobile platform requirements in Salesforce release checklist
2. What patch changes could have caused the issue so that we can work on the solution